# C# Optimize Conditional in Loop where input is a value that needs to be between a start/end value found in each list item

Tags: c#, optimization

**EDIT: This is a general problem when you are stuck in a situation that you have to use a List instead of a Dictionary because instead of searching for a key you may be searching for a range of number like a text minimum and maximum index, and each item may have inner items in them, in my case it added up to 100k+ items before I found a workable solution just after posting this question.**

**Solution below involves partitioning the list into smaller chunks, much like database indexing.**

I call the following a lot in a particular project. It works fine, but there's a problem with this as far as optimization is concerned. I have an index and need to get all text spans where the index is between the start and end, as shown below.

**Example:**

```
List<Lexer.Span> spans = new List<Lexer.Span>();
for (int i1 = 0; i1 < input.OrganizedSpans.Count; i1++)
{
   Lexer.Span span1 = input.OrganizedSpans[i1];
   if (index >= span1.Start && index < span1.End) { spans.Add(span1); }
}
```

...

```
public class Lexer {
...
    public class Span
    {
        public int Start {get;set;}
        public int End {get;set;}
        public string Text {get;set;}
        public List<Span> InnerSpans {get;set;} = new List<Span>();
    }
}
```

OrganizedSpans has 6,000+ items stemming from lexemes tokenized of an 18k HTML document, so it gets weighed down significantly doing a straight iteration. I will show you a partitioning optimization in the answer that will help in situations like this. **It brought my execution down from a few seconds to near-instantaneous.**

Original: *It works, but is a bottleneck according to the Visual Studio Profiler on the if conditional line. It gets called quite a bit from the parser code.
*Is there a faster way to do what I want to do here?* I've looked at several optimization articles and stackoverflow posts, but am having trouble finding it.*

**UPDATE: Yes there is. :)**

Comment: If the input space is large and ordered you could do a binary search to find the first item where index >= start and from there where index <= end, I guess. This will save walking over the entire collection of spans. Having to sort them first if they aren't, night negate this benefit if you access OrganizedSpans only once. If instead a lot of items match, chances are that the List<T> needs to resize its internal arrays. Please provide some more context and numbers.

Comment: @CodeCaster updated, and found an interesting answer that came to mind right after I posted and was off to get lunch. Answer was building a rudimentary b-tree-esque partition. Parser is working near-instantaneously now.

Answer (score 1):

The answer is simple, partition your lists into smaller lists, here's an example code:

List Partition Building, replace Span and Lexer for whatever you need to partition, in my case it was a syntax node tree of text from an LL(1) parser:

```
public class LexerResult
{
    public class ResultPartition
    {
        public int Minimum { get; set; }
        public int Maximum { get; set; }
        public List<Span> Spans { get; set; }
    }
    public List<Span> RawSpans { get; set; }
    public List<Span> OrganizedSpans { get; set; }
    public List<ResultPartition> OrganizedPartitions { get; set; }
...
```

Partition Method:

```
public List<LexerResult.ResultPartition> OrganizePartitions(List<Span> spans, int partitionSize = 300)
{
    List<LexerResult.ResultPartition> partitions = new List<LexerResult.ResultPartition>();
    bool done = false;
    int recordsProcessed = 0;
    while(!done)
    {
        int recordsNeeded = 0;
        if (recordsProcessed + partitionSize > spans.Count)
        {
            recordsNeeded = spans.Count - recordsProcessed;
            done = true;
        }
        else
        {
            recordsNeeded = partitionSize;
        }
        int recordsNeededEnd = recordsProcessed + recordsNeeded;
        int min = Int32.MaxValue;
        int max = Int32.MinValue;
        List<Span> partition = new List<Span>();
        for(int i=recordsProcessed;i<recordsNeededEnd;i++)
        {
            Span span = spans[i];
            min = Math.Min(span.Start, min);
            max = Math.Max(span.End, max);
            partition.Add(span);
        }
        recordsProcessed += recordsNeeded;
        LexerResult.ResultPartition resultPartition = new LexerResult.ResultPartition()
        {
            Spans = partition,
            Maximum = max,
            Minimum = min
        };
        partitions.Add(resultPartition);
    }
    return partitions;
}
```

Usage:

```
List<Lexer.Span> spans = new List<Lexer.Span>();
for(int i1=0;i1<input.OrganizedPartitions.Count;i1++)
{
    Lexer.LexerResult.ResultPartition partition = input.OrganizedPartitions[i1];
    if (partition.Minimum <= index && index < partition.Maximum)
    {
        List<Lexer.Span> spans_1a = partition.Spans;
        for (int i3 = 0; i3 < spans_1a.Count; i3++)
        {
            Lexer.Span span_1a = spans_1a[i3];
            if (span_1a.Start <= index && index < span_1a.End)
            {
                spans.Add(span_1a);
            }
        }
    }
...
}
```

Note: Using **for** instead of **foreach** does seem to clock faster in Visual Studio's Profiler.

So I'm taking a minimum and maximum from each span and building partitions that have a min/max property you can use for easily seeing which data points have a start and end surrounding whatever index you supply.

I didn't see this mentioned on any of the articles and posts I read about optimizing .NET code so it seemed worth mention. The program I'm writing is running near-instantaneous and soon to be released after some testing/documentation.